# Obtain a view of a DataFrame using the loc method

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to obtain a view of a pandas dataframe using the `loc` method but it is not working as expected when I am modifying the original DataFrame.
I want to extract a row/slice of a DataFrame using the `loc` method so that when a modification is done to the DataFrame, the slice reflects the change.

Let's have a look at this example:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':np.arange(0,5,2), 'a':np.arange(3), 'b':np.arange(3)}).set_index('ID')
df
    a   b
ID      
0   0   0
2   1   1
4   2   2
```

Now I create a slice using loc:

```py
slice1 = df.loc[[2],]
slice1

    a   b
ID      
2   1   1
```

Then I modify the original DataFrame:

```py
df.loc[2, 'b'] = 9
df

    a   b
ID      
0   0   0
2   1   9
4   2   2
```

But unfortunately our slice does not reflect this modification as I would be expecting for a view:

```py
slice1
    a   b
ID      
2   1   1
```

My expectation:

```py
    a   b
ID      
2   1   9
```

I found an ugly fix using a mix of `iloc` and `loc` but I hope there is a nicer way to obtain the result I am expecting.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: You mean when you change 'df', slice1 should reflect the change automatically? I dont think thats possible.

Comment: Yes, this is mentioned in [this doc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy)

Comment: I agree with Anshul.  I believe it's designed to work the other way around. You take a slice, change a value in the slice and then the original df is updated.

Comment: I was wondering because I can do this kind of modifications with iloc: `slice2 = df.iloc[1:2,:]` and then it reflects the change when df is updated.

Comment: Actually I am confused now. I tried something I am sharing in the 'Answer' section. Not an answer in anyway but looking to clarify my doubt.

Comment: @MitchellvanZuylen I have tried the other way around and it did not work either

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is not an answer.

I tried testing how over-writing the values in chained assignment vs .loc referring to the pandas documentation link that was shared by @Quang Hoang above.

This is what I tried:

```
dfmi = pd.DataFrame([list('abcd'),
   list('efgh'),
   list('ijkl'),
   list('mnop')],
   columns=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['one', 'two'],
   ['first', 'second']]))

df1 = dfmi['one']['second']
df2 = dfmi.loc[:, ('one', 'second')]
```

Output of both df1 and df2:

```
0    b
1    f
2    j
3    n
```

Iteration 1:

```
value = ['z', 'x', 'c', 'v']
dfmi['one']['second'] = value
```

Output df1:

```
0    z
1    x
2    c
3    v
```

Iteration 2:

```
value = ['z', 'x', 'c', 'v']
dfmi.loc[:, ('one', 'second')] = value
```

Output df2:

```
0    z
1    x
2    c
3    v
```

The assignment of new sets is changing the values in both the cases.

The documentation says:

Quote 1: 'method 2 (.loc) is much preferred over method 1 (chained [])'

Quote 2:
'Outside of simple cases, it’s very hard to predict whether "**getitem**" (used by chained option) will return a view or a copy (it depends on the memory layout of the array, about which pandas makes no guarantees), and therefore whether the "**setitem**" (used by .loc) will modify dfmi or a temporary object that gets thrown out immediately afterward.'

I am not able to understand the explanation above. If the value in dfmi can change (in my case) and may not change (like in Benoit's case) then which way to obtain the result? Not sure if I am missing a point here.
Looking for help

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I have slightly modified your example by taking only one row: `df2 = dfmi.loc[[1], ('one', 'second')]` and then modifying the original df as following: `dfmi.loc[1, ('one', 'second')] = 'z'`. Then the change is not visible anymore into the `df2` slice...  
I also have tried the opposite by changing directly in the slice: `df2.loc[1] = 'z'` and the change is not fed back to the `dfmi` dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the slice didn't reflect the changes you made in the original dataframe is b/c you created the slice first.

When you create a slice, you create a "copy" of a slice of the data. You're not directly linking the two.

The short answer here is that you have two options 1) changed the original df first, then create a slice 2) don't slice, just do your operations referencing the original df using .loc or iloc

Answer (score 0):

The memory address of your dataframe and slice are different, so changes in dataframe won't reflect in the slice-

[image: Different memory addresses]

The answer is to change the value in the dataframe and then slice it -

[image: Correct output]