# How to optimize pandas DataFrames slices copies?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have to deal with pretty big pandas DataFrames and I am looking for advice on how I could optimize my workflow. I basically have 2 main dataframes named "data" and "constants", here is a dummy example:

```
constants = pd.DataFrame({'ID':np.arange(1,3), 'Callsign':['AAA', 'BBB'],
                          'to':[1, 0], 'ADEP':['LSGG', None]})
constants
    ID  Callsign    to  ADEP
0   1   AAA     1   LSGG
1   2   BBB     0   None

data = pd.DataFrame({'ID':[1, 1, 1, 2, 2],
                     'time':pd.date_range(start='1/1/2018', end='1/05/2018'),
                     'Lon':[8.1, 8.15, 8.2, 8.6, 8.55],
                     'Lat':[45.1, 45.15, 45.2, 45.6, 45.55]})
data
    ID  time    Lon     Lat
0   1   2018-01-01  8.10    45.10
1   1   2018-01-02  8.15    45.15
2   1   2018-01-03  8.20    45.20
3   2   2018-01-04  8.60    45.60
4   2   2018-01-05  8.55    45.55
```

Those pieces of data are belonging to trajectories and I want to create for each trajectory an instance of a Trajectory object which contains the slice of each original DataFrame that share the same "ID". So far I did it that way:

```
class Trajectory():
  def __init__(self, constants, data):
    self.constants = constants,
    self.data = data

trajs_dict = {ids: Trajectory(constants.loc[constants.ID == ids],
                              data.loc[data.ID == ids])
              for ids in constants.ID.unique()}
```

Now the issue is that, instead of creating a view of my original DataFrames, it creates a copy: (cf my previous [so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61890845/obtain-a-view-of-a-dataframe-using-the-loc-method))

```
trajs_dict[1].data._is_view
False
```

Therefore it does not optimize my memory. Do you have any idea how I could optmize my workflow to save some memory?

Bonus point: Would it be possible that the original DataFrames ("data" and "constants") reflect the change I could do on a slice (ie: at the object level) ex: `trajs_dict[1].constants.to = 0`,  and the other way around (The slice reflects the change I do on the original "constants" and "data" DataFrames).